# Passing contexual filters

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a view in drupal 7  here is attached screenshot 
[image: View Screen Shot]

Here

And preview of this Screen Shot is  or output of this view is

[image: OutPut]

Which is working fine .

Now when i try to pass contextual filter see [image: this screen]

Named Edmonton it shows following result

[image: This resul]

And Result is not correct

It must show only filter with edmonton name

Any Body has idea what is the problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show the details of your contextual filter?

Answer (score 0):

I think the implementation has some issues. The first contextual filter that you have added is date, right and when you are passing an argument, it's not a date. Is that a username? If so then you need to use proper contextual filer. You have a filter as "Add Property View" and also the same in Contextual Filer.

Comment: i am passing date filter by default date . i am using Calender module.which atomically picks date

Comment: 'edmonton' is a user name of who create a node?

Comment: Try using 'Content: Author uid' under contextual filter and filter by user id.